# OSError: [Errno 121] Remote IO error running donkey calibrate

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, adafruit

i am using the donkeycar library and i have just received an IO error upon running the donkey calibrate command, below is the complete error

```
using donkey v2.2.1 ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/dk/bin/donkey", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('donkeycar', 'console_scripts', 'donkey')()
  File "/home/pi/donkeycar/donkeycar/management/base.py", line 426, in execute_from_command_line
    c.run(args[2:])
  File "/home/pi/donkeycar/donkeycar/management/base.py", line 152, in run
    c = PCA9685(channel)
  File "/home/pi/donkeycar/donkeycar/parts/actuator.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.pwm = Adafruit_PCA9685.PCA9685()
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/dk/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Adafruit_PCA9685/PCA9685.py", line 75, in __init__
    self.set_all_pwm(0, 0)
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/dk/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Adafruit_PCA9685/PCA9685.py", line 111, in set_all_pwm
    self._device.write8(ALL_LED_ON_L, on & 0xFF)
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/dk/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Adafruit_GPIO/I2C.py", line 114, in write8
    self._bus.write_byte_data(self._address, register, value)
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/dk/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Adafruit_PureIO/smbus.py", line 236, in write_byte_data
    self._device.write(data)
OSError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error
```

I am not sure how to solve it i have enabled the I2C pins on the RP3 including remote GPIO

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45324851/smbus-on-the-rpi-gives-ioerror-errno-121-remote-i-o-error